# Capistrano 3.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, capistrano, sidekiq

Has any one used `Capistrano 3.0.0` ? 
I'm new to rails and web development in general, and I've never used Capistrano before, and I need to deploy my app on Heroku with `Capistrano` in order to user `sidekiq` and `redis-server`.
Should I use an older version of Capistrano, where I could find more resource to help get started, or is this considered a bad thing ?
Any suggestions or tips would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest using version v2 because of [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/capistrano/nmMaqWR1z84/hdjAGIGbwdYJ).

Comment: why do you need to use Capistrano to achieve this on Heroku?

Comment: James, as the OP of the thread you linked, I'm not sure I understand your reasoning? V2 is completely unsupported now, and v3 has a raft of excited, and capable maintainers improving things every day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano and Heroku are not compatible technology.

Heroku provides a git source control remote server.  When you want to deploy code onto your Heroku app, you use git to push a copy of the code.  This triggers a Heroku deployment through their process.

Capistrano is an SSH based system deployment framework.  It allows you to connect via SSH to each server in your environment and issue commands with a large library of built-in functionality.  Heroku does not allow SSH access to configure systems.

Do you have deploys/configuration working on Heroku at all?  If not, you should start there with the basic Heroku Rails setup documents.

If you do have your web app running, but need Redis and Sidekiq, you will need to:

- Provision a Redis database provider, like OpenRedis via a Heroku Addon: http://addons.heroku.com/
- Setup Sidekiq in your Rails application (See Sidekiq docs: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)
- Add a Sidekiq worker process in your Heroku `Procfile` within your app

Your app will then have a number of `web` processes from the `Procfile` running your Rails app front-end and a number of back-end asynchronous workers running Sidekiq.